# Kendo Telerik MVC3/ RAZOR - Object doesn't support property or method 'kendoGrid'

Tags: grid, telerik, kendo-ui

I am using .NET 4 MVC. I am just trying to create a very simple grid functionality. When I try to run the application I am getting

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'kendoGrid' error.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here are the code snippets

```
        public ActionResult Products_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var mock = new MaintainEmployeeMock();
            return Json(mock.GetEmployeeInfoForAdminScreen().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
View:

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.EMP_ID).Groupable(false).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.FName).Width(120);
        columns.Bound(p => p.MName).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.LName).Width(120);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Emp_Type).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Emp_Shift).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Menu_Level).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Super_ID).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Active_Y_N).Width(50);
    }) 
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "EmployeeAdmin"))
    )
)
```

Comment: Are you including the necessary javascript dependencies (i.e. kendo.all.min.js and kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js) in your project?

Answer (score 2):

All the possible reasons for such error are covered in the troubleshoot section [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/troubleshooting).

I assume you either load the jQuery library too many times, or you do not load the kendo scripts at all.

Answer (score 0):

Is that all your view code? Check if there is any javascript not being rendered on the page.

Also, as Brett pointed out, you have to make sure that all necessary JS is included either by using cdn or putting the files on your app structure.

Another thing, are you trying to access the grid client side?